# PHP SoapClient auto escaping already escaped characters

Tags: php, xml, soap, escaping

I am sending some data to a SoapService that contains escaped currency symbols. For example `&#160;&#8364;` for the Euro symbol. However, when `SoapClient::__soapCall` is called, the strings are being escaped again so it ends up looking like `&amp;#160;&amp;#8364;`

Here's how I'm doing the call:

```
$params = new \stdClass();
$params->recipient = new \stdClass();
$params->recipient->name = "Some buyer";
$params->recipient->email = "test@test.com";
$params->data = new \stdClass();
$params->data->name = "total";
$params->data->value = "91,04&#160;&#8364;"

$soap = new \SoapClient(); //Skipping the usual settings for the sake of brevity
$soap->__soapCall('send', [$params]);
```

I'm actually using a class that extends `SoapClient` to stub out the method that calls `SoapClient::__soapCall`, but that is not affecting the payload. I've checked that up until the point when `SoapClient::__soapCall` is called it all looks as described above.

Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is encoded, changing `&#160;&#8364;` to `&amp;#160;&amp;#8364;` for the purposes of escaping it to be inserted into XML.  If you look at it on the receiving end, when it comes out it would be converted back to `&#160;&#8364;`.  So **what you put in is what comes out**.

So it is more a matter of making sure you are sending the data in format that the receiving end needs it to be in.  If your data has HTML entities but the receiving end needs the normal non-entity version, then `html_entity_decode()` the data.  It is the same as if you were making a call locally, if that local method does not work with entities then you better decode those entities before hand.

If you are doing the encoding specifically because you know that it is going to be inserted into the XML, then you are doing an extra step as the soap client already does this for you.  Just stick in whatever needs to be coming out on the other end.